# Does truesight see the attacker if they have used Steel Wind Strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

The spell text of [Steel Wind Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/steel-wind-strike) (XGtE, p. 166) states the caster 'vanishes', which some argue means [the caster is treated as 'unseen'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176830/do-you-get-advantage-on-the-steel-wind-strike-spells-attacks-because-you-vanis).

If that were the case, does that mean the caster is visible to somebody with [Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight)?

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness, see *invisible creatures* and objects, automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them, and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic. Furthermore, the monster can see into the Ethereal Plane within the same range.

Emphasis mine.

Are they visible during the attacks? They aren't invisible, just 'unseen'. This is relevant, if say they start from a position that obscures their face, and the being with Truesight wants to recognise them later.

Comment: The question you've cited already hinges on the interpretation of the word "vanish" in the spell's text, which isn't given a precise definition in the rules. I don't think you're going to get any more precision in that definition by asking a 2nd question about it.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson This question is assuming the definition, and I'm sort of asking can Truesight see stuff that's unseen but not invisible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### IF they would be invisible, then yes. But it doesn't seem like they are.

We are back in "spells do only what they say they do" territory, and the spell says:

> You flourish the weapon used in the casting and then vanish to strike
> like the wind. Choose up to five creatures you can see within range.
> Make a melee spell attack against each target. On a hit, a target
> takes 6d10 force damage.

And even if it does say that you vanish, the first sentence seems to merely be fluff. It doesn't say that you attack in any manner that would give you advantage on the attack.
As stated by the top rated answer in the linked question, and the Jeremy tweet linked in there, it does not grant you invisibility.

***Like everything, the DM could*** rule that you DO turn invisible, in which case  **Truesight** would negate the advantage, at least RAW.

But "vanishing" could also be disappearing physically. Now you aren't invisible, in fact you aren't there at all.
This – at least to me – seems to be the intended function of the spell.
It makes you do a series of fast teleportations between enemies, and attack along the way. So to actually attack, you need to reappear.
The fact that we are doing a series of teleportations is reinforced by the last row of the spell:

> You can then teleport to an unoccupied space you can see within 5 feet
> of one of the targets you hit or missed.

---

*"I'm sort of asking can Truesight see stuff that's unseen but not invisible?"*
In what ways can you be unseen, but not invisible?
As far as I know, only in two ways:

1. Physically obstructed, "hiding" – behind a wall, in a bush, so on.
2. By not being in range of vision.

Truesight helps with neither of these, unless the target is hidden by magical darkness, or outside your *Darkvision* range.

Comment: I like all of this answer, except ", the first sentence seems to merely be fluff" because [there is not flavour text in spell descriptions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012/48827).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Fair, I guess, but that doesn't negate the fact that "flourishing your weapon" and "vanish to strike like the wind" has no mechanical impact on anything.

Comment: Au contraire, there's numerous [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A176830) that assert it does make you 'unseen' and/or 'invisible'. I'll still accept this though, as I personally think that bit of text is silly.