# What are the benefits of pouring all of your Ki into Water Whip, as a Way of the Four Elements monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk

What benefit(s) does pouring all of your Ki points into Water Whip provide, as a Way of the Four Elements monk?

This question is a follow up to some efforts to improve the Way of the Four Elements monk choice [as discussed here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152842/22566).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It gives you the best increase *over* your usual damage per Ki points spent

When you spend a limited resource, the question is never how much damage you make, but how much *more* damage you make than without this resource<sup>1</sup>.

As from level 5 your base Water Whip  damage is *below* your normal weapon damage<sup>2</sup>, each ki point spent increases not only the *absolute* damage output, but also the rate at which your damage increases *over* your usual damage.

### On 12th level

With your usual Martial Arts you do 28.5 damage (2*(1d8+5)+1d8+5). No KP spent (**Base** damage).
With Water Whip you do 16.5 damage (3d10) for 2 KP (**WW** damage).

So the increase is:
$$\frac{WW - Base}{Base}/KP$$

For 2 Ki points you gain **-21%** damage *over* your usual damage output **per ki point spent**. (If you spend only 2 KP, you *decrease* your damage by 42%, -21% per KP)
For 12 Ki points, you gain **12.6%** of damage *over* your usual damage output **per ki point spent**. (If you spend all your KP, you *increase* your damage by 150%, 12.6% per KP)

[image: Water Whip damage increase over usual damage per Ki point]

So the problem with Water Whip is that the more Ki points you spend on it, the better improvement each *next* Ki point brings. This favors spending all your Ki points at once.

---

<sup>1</sup> this is why Divine Smite is great, and [Mordenkainen's Sword is not](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/145596/9552)
<sup>2</sup> with Martial Arts, at 5th level it is 2*(1d8+4)+1d6+4 = 24.5 damage<sup>3</sup>, against 16.5 from Water Whip
<sup>3</sup> You [can and should use weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72289/9552) to increase your damage output

Comment: I believe many sources recommend it because it was a bonus action to use, before erratas changed it to an action.

Comment: Flurry of blows is more damage per ki point.

Comment: The issue is that images are not very accessible. (Though I don't personally know how much more accessible MathJax is to screen readers and the like.) That said, it might be worth asking on [meta] if there is an easy way to automatically convert a table to [MathJax](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/mathjax-latex-in-posts-is-live).

Comment: @Miniman not only is it more damage per ki point, it is _on top_ of your usual damage, not instead of it

Comment: So then why is water whip the best damage increase per ki point spent?

Comment: @Miniman the title is too long as it is, but what I meant to say is that if you choose to use Water Whip, you should spend all your Ki points on it. FoB provides better increase per KP, but you can't spend more than 1 KP per round on it.